# Writing JSON data into BigQuery table as just one field of type string

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My input data looks like this:

```
[someGarbagevalue]{"Id": 1, "Address": {"Street":"MG Road","City":"Pune"}}
[someGarbagevalue]{"Id": 2, "Address": {"City":"Mumbai"}}
[someGarbagevalue]{"Id": 3, "Address": {"Street":"XYZ Road"}}
[someGarbagevalue]{"Id": 4}
[someGarbagevalue]{"Id": 5, "PhoneNumber": 12345678, "Address": {"Street":"ABCD Road", "City":"Bangalore"}}
```

I am striping the `[someGarbagevalue]` after reading the data as and then trying to write to BigQuery:

```
class processFunction(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    global line
    line = element[element.find(']') + 1:].strip()
    return [line]

def run(argv=None):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
      first = p | 'read' >> ReadFromText(wordcount_options.input)
      second = (first
                | 'process' >> (beam.ParDo(processFunction()))
                | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                  'myBucket:tableFolder.test_table')
```

**Question**:

1. How can I write the data to BigQuery as each `line` of type
   `STRING`.
2. How would I query the BigQuery Table if I write the data to BigQuery as each line?

Current error:

```
Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Value encountered without start of object.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things missing/wrong with your code:

1. Why do you use `global line` in `processFunction`? It's not required there.
2. You should specify BigQuery table schema in your `WriteToBigQuery`
3. `processFunction` should return dictionary with field from schema. The value of this field should be your string.

Your code should look more or less like this:

```
class processFunction(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    line = element[element.find(']') + 1:].strip()
    return {
        "line": line
    }

def run(argv=None):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
      first = p | 'read' >> ReadFromText(wordcount_options.input)
      second = (first
                | 'process' >> (beam.ParDo(processFunction()))
                | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                  'myBucket:tableFolder.test_table',schema="line:STRING")
```

Comment: Removed `global line` and specified schema in `WriteToBigQuery`. I am still getting the same error.

```Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1., error: Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1., error: Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Value encountered without start of object.```

Comment: Did you create BigQuery table by yourself? Check types. Also check that your input data is corrent.

Comment: Yes, I created the table. `[
  {
    "name": "line",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "nullable"
  } ]`. 
Input data is similar to one mentioned in the question where I am stripping out the initial square brackets and returning the nested JSON to WriteToBigQuery.

Comment: What output do you get when you write to file instead of BigQuery? Is it expected output?

Comment: ah! I did that now. The output to my text file is the word `line`. How can I fix this?

Comment: For starters change `return` in `processFunction` to `yield`